# How can I set up a local SSL certificate and a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, puma, foreman

This might be a two-in-one question.

1. I have a Rails application for home/hobby usage, hosted on a Raspberry Pi and I was wondering if it's possible to create a local SSL certificate for it and setup Rails to use it?
2. If yes, how can I setup my Rails/Puma/Foreman/Ubuntu application? For now, I am running the application with Foreman, by using a Procfile:

   ```
   web: bundle exec puma -t 8:8 -p 3000
   worker: bundle exec sidekiq
   clock: bundle exec clockwork config/clock.rb
   ```

Comment: The puma readme suggests that you can do this with the -b option

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes you can.  Here is a gist explaining the process:

https://gist.github.com/tadast/9932075

2. My procfile contains an entry that looks like this:

   server: rails server puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?key=server.key&cert=server.crt'

This seems to work for me.  I also set

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

in config/application.rb

I gathered info about it from all these places:

https://github.com/puma/puma

http://www.railway.at/2013/02/12/using-ssl-in-your-local-rails-environment/

http://www.panozzaj.com/blog/2013/08/12/how-to-set-up-local-https-development/

http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/14-config-force_ssl-is-different-than-controller-force_ssl

Comment: Hey, I did all of the following steps and I all I get is `No such key file 'server.key'` and I see my `server.key` file generated in the `.ssh` folder. Any ideas?