# Force HTTPS/SSL for all controller/request specs in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using RSpec 3.5.0, and would like to enable HTTPS/SSL requests for all my specs.

Since I added `force_ssl` to my `ApplicationController`, all my specs are failing, since they are redirecting to the secure version of the site instead of rendering, etc.

Comment: Do you need to force SSL for all environments? You could omit test `force_ssl unless Rails.env.test?` or perhaps only force SSL for production: `force_ssl if Rails.env.production?`

Comment: That's true, I could do that. Still wondering if there is an answer to my original question, though.

Comment: You could set up your local environment to use a self-signed SSL certificate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991868/how-can-i-setup-a-local-ssl-certificate-and-a-rails-application

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't solve my issue with testing

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785261/test-an-https-ssl-request-in-rspec-rails

Comment: Yes I did see that, but that is only for one spec, and does not apply to all of them. For the `request.env['HTTPS']` method, I could apply this to all my specs easily, but that method is for an outdated version of RSpec...

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions here don't work under rails 5.  If that's part of where you're stuck adding `https!` to your spec should work.

Comment: how can that be done in the case of something like 
`expect(response).to redirect_to company_path(company)` ?


(the error is 
`Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/companies/1310> but was a redirect to <https://www.example.com/companies/1310>`